# Is it possible to temporarily turn off an Oracle cluster?

Tags: oracle, cluster-computing

So that I can use direct pathing for data loading?  Can you turn off a cluster temporarily until data is loaded and then turn everything back on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this questions is related to your other question regarding using SQL*Loader direct path. I believe the restriction on using direct path in SQL*Loader is that the table should not be clustered. If the table you are inserting data is not clustered, you can use direct path whether your Oracle instance is clustered or not.

So, if your table is not clustered, you should be able to use direct path loading without turning Oracle clustering off. If your table is cluster, you are completely out of luck because converting it to a non-clustered table and then clustering it back after the data is loaded would negate any performance gains from the direct path loading.

Comment: if I do a cluster_database = false and get exclusive rights, load with direct path, the put it back in the RAC, won't it sync back up?  Won't that give me my faster time?  Are you saying that some tables may not be clustered while the instance itself is?

Comment: My understanding is that Oracle clustering (RAC) and clustered tables are two completely different concepts that just had a misfortune to have similar names.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two completely different concepts:

```
- a database cluster and
- a table cluster.
```

A database cluster provides scalability and HA, while the other (table cluster) determines how and where to physically store the data. Turning off RAC will not help with table clusters.